# how to escape a while loop with a single words from a sentence

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I want to be able to have the user import the sentence "find key" or "get key" and the while loop recognize the "key" part in each sentence and accept that as an answer to exit the while loop.

```
#############Phase0#############
print("\nWelcome to your Adventure", flush=True)
time.sleep(2.1)
print("\nyour story begins here", flush=True)
time.sleep(2.1)
cls()

#############Phase1#############
print("\nYou find yourself in a dark empty room")
print("\nwhat would you like to do ?")
print(movesList,"\n")

prompt2 = str(input(' '))
while prompt2 != "up":
    if prompt2 != "up":
        print("There is nothing there\n")
        prompt2 = str(input('what would you like to do ?')) 
        break    

cls()
print("You arrive at the door\n")
print("butthe door is locked......\n")
prompt3 = str(input(' '))
while prompt3 != "key":
    if prompt3 != "key":
        print('That wont open the door...\n')
        prompt3 = str(input('what would you like to do: \n'))
    else:
        print("you've unlocked the door")

print("YOUVE ESCAPEDD!!!!!!!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
prompt3 = input(' ')
while "key" not in prompt3.lower():
    #if "key" not in prompt3.lower():
    print('That wont open the door...\n')
    prompt3 = input('what would you like to do: \n')
    #else:
        #print("you've unlocked the door")

print("YOUVE ESCAPEDD!!!!!!!!")
```

Instead of explicitly checking whether prompt3 was equal to 'key', you should check if 'key' is contained within prompt3 by using the "in" keyword.

Some other adjustments I made:

1. `str(input(' '))` is unneccessary. `input(' ')` will do, since it is already a string.
2. Use `"key" not in prompt3.lower()` instead of `"key" not in prompt3`. This is so that if the user inputs "KEY" instead of "key", the code will still pick it up.
3. The sections I have commented out are unnecessary. The if statement is not required as the while statement already (in a way) replaces it. If you run the code, the else statement does not run, since as soon as the user inputs "key", the while loop breaks.

Hope this helps.